# Any recommendations on how to create Random Forest Classifier on a list of words?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, random-forest

I recently read a paper "Political Image Analysis with Deep Neural Networks", where the authors ran object detection on images. After the objects were detected, the strings of the found objects (if it met a certain probability threshold) were used as features in training and testing a Random Forest classifier for the image class. From the paper, they were trying to classify an image as coming from a Republican or Democrat Senate member, based on what objects were found in the image.

I'm trying to recreate something similar, but I'm having trouble finding a way to implement the second component of the random forest. I was able to successfully run the object detection on the images with two object detection component, but I'm having trouble coming up with a plan on how to feed these to a random forest.

Here are the features from my data frame, just broken up into some variables for simplicity, where labels of `-1,0,1` are the label I am aiming for.

```
labels_res = ["suit", "Loafer", "unicycle", "Scottish deerhound", "trench coat"]
scores_res = [0.39158088, 0.19913094, 0.026774898, 0.022956373, 0.01655933]
labels_vgg = ["Loafer", "suit", "jean", "minivan", "unicycle"]
scores_vgg = [0.08161158, 0.073884524, 0.059617866, 0.049262974, 0.037928864]
label = -1
```

Obviously, most of these specific objects aren't helpful(as the probabilities are quite low), but its more of the general concept that I'm asking for help with.

Does anyone have a recommendation on how to take the objects found in `labels_res` and `labels_vgg` and use those to train an RF classifier with the data set up in this manner?

I appreciate any input!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the paper, but I would assume that they treat the word labels from the object detection NN simply like a piece of text, which they run through a classic document classification pipeline, using a random forest classifier.

So if you Google for "document classification" or "bag of words" you should easily find what to do. Scikit-Learn has examples for this in the docs. Your "documents" are the list of object classes from the NN object detector.

You can of course use any classifier that can work with broad sparse inputs, which are typical for bag of words. Does not have to be Random Forest.

It would be interesting to see whether adding the probabilities returned from the NN as additional feature improves performance.